# iText to generate a pdf via servlets from a dynamic mapped jsp page with input data

Tags: pdf, web-applications, servlets, itext, bytearrayoutputstream

I have used byte array output stream to generate pdf however the  input is a mapping of a jsp page and  webbased data this mapped document is to be used to generate a pdf

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
document.open();
document.add(new Paragraph(webDoc));
document.close();
response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
response.setHeader("Cache-Control","must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
baos.writeTo(os);
os.flush();
```

The webdoc used here in document.add() is a mapped data from jsp and output of some data inputs, but instead pdf following page gets displaed

%PDF-1.4 %2 0 obj <>stream x@<ńĤpٶB>SAa]"1zo&"k0;(\pxՃe#z,G%SQS^]P/@h |\" Ȉ[`JJrf6$m}M Ʉ:+t$j- y HBt: uR؞{bz{yK 3CZ"Uy2i>>/MediaBox[0 0 595 842]>> endobj 1 0 obj <> endobj 3 0 obj <> endobj 5 0 obj <> endobj 6 0 obj <> endobj xref 0 7 0000000000 65535 f 0000000555 00000 n 0000000015 00000 n 0000000643 00000 n 0000000398 00000 n 0000000706 00000 n 0000000751 00000 n trailer <<1715206131a4d7dfbf6cef534ceaa665>]/Info 6 0 R/Size 7>> startxref 887 %%EOF

My web.xml has the servlet mapping too but have a doubt in the url pattern as the generated pdf will be dynamic so in the url-pattern section I have /servlet/servlet_name.

Using *.pdf did not help.

Comment: Was the content type set previously in the code? Were any bytes previously output? I read somewhere that PDF plugins are picky about getting the content length set correctly, too. And, obviously, your browser has to have a PDF plugin installed. (Those are the raw character contents of the PDF file.)

Comment: Are you using the correct character encoding for the input webDoc?